# PHP Associative array inserting as indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I need an associative array with this structure (keys are strings, values are indexed arrays), and I'm appending elements dynamically.

```
Array(
 ["itemCategory"]=> Array("itemName", "itemName"...)
 ["itemCategory"]=> Array("itemName", "itemName"...)
 ...
)
```

However, I cannot seem to form an array within an associative array when I do this (as requested, I've added the MySQLi code):

```
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
"SELECT b.id, b.type, b.name, b.street, b.city, b.state, b.zipcode, b.phone,  b.website, b.hours, b.latitude, b.longitude, c.id, c.name, i.id, i.name
FROM business b LEFT JOIN business_category_item bci ON bci.bid = b.id
LEFT JOIN category c ON c.id=bci.cid LEFT JOIN item i ON i.id = bci.iid"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if(!$stmt->bind_result($bID,$bT,$bN,$bStr,$bC,$bSta,$bZ,$bP,$bW,$bH,$bLat,$bLng,$cI,$cN,$iI,$iN)){
    echo "Bind failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqlii->connect_error;
}

$arr=array();
while($row=$stmt->fetch()){
    $arr[$cN][]=$iN; //gettype($cN) returns "string"
}
```

I have also tried array_push() without luck (undefined index error):

```
array_push($arr[$cN],$iN);
```

When I print my array, it always prints like this:

```
print_r($arr, true);  

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "MP3 player"
            [1] => "Computers"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "Tank tops"
            [1] => "Blankets"
            [2] => "Shirts"
        )
)
```

instead of what I need, which is:

```
Array
(
    ["electronics"] => Array
        (
            [0] => "MP3 player"
            [1] => "Computers"
        )

    ["clothing"] => Array
        (
            [0] => "Tank tops"
            [1] => "Blankets"
            [2] => "Shirts"
        )
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you've written looks like it should work. Are you sure `$cName` is set correctly?

Comment: you're using `mysqli`? show the `->bind_result()` part, where most likely `$cName` is set

Comment: Please post the actual code, especially the part that sets `$cName`.

Comment: Hi @Barmar. Yes, when I `echo $cName;` and `echo gettype($cName);` I correctly get the category as well as the type "string".

Comment: @Barmar, I've added the MySQLi code.

Comment: You have a serious syntax error, you're missing the ending quote for the `SELECT` string. How is this possibly running>?

Comment: Look at the color highlighting.

Comment: @Barmar, I accidentally deleted the last quotation when I was pasting it in. In my code, the quotes are correct.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://ideone.com/2nt3Y4

Comment: Problem solved! See below. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I believe I've solved this. When I use `var_dump($arr);`, it correctly prints as an associative array. When I used `print_r($arr);`, it prints as an indexed array. I am not sure why this is.</strike>

EDIT: Actually, the problem was that I sorted the array using sort($arr) before printing it.

Comment: I've never seen anything like this.

Comment: Did you look at my demo on ideone.com? It uses `print_r` and it prints correctly as an associative array.

Comment: This would happen if you did something like `print_r(array_values($arr))`. But I don't believe that just switching from `print_r()` to `var_dump()`, without changing anything else, would solve it.

Comment: Answer revised. I forgot that I sorted the array before printing it, which caused my problem.

Comment: But you didn't sort the array before printing it with `var_dump`?

Comment: Use `asort` instead of `sort`, and it will keep the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it simpler and use something like this instead:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT...");
if ($result->num_rows) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $arr[$row['id']][] = $row['name'];
    }
}
```

You will get lost very easily in all these numerous variables with undecipherable names that you make in the `bind_result()`.

Comment: I appreciate the style tips. However, I've solved my issue. See below.

Comment: No worries. Just trying to save you some potential headache in the long term.

Comment: He's using `mysqli`, not `PDO`.

Comment: My bad. In this case, the `fetch()` behaviour should obviously be modified to return an associative array.

Comment: `$stmt->fetch()` returns a boolean, not an associative array.

Comment: @Barmar my bad again. I haven't used mysqli a lot.